# Conditional query in fetching data between two dates with interval

Tags: mysql, date, max, intervals

SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `TrackDate` between DATE_SUB("2015-01-12 13:47:30", INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND "2015-01-12 13:47:30"

**mytable**

```
**id-----------|-----keyword(varchar)----|--------trackdate(timestamp)**

1------------|--------a------------------------|-------2015-01-12 13:47:02
15------------|------ *NULL* ----------------------|-------2015-01-12 12:47:02

2------------|--------b------------------------|-------2015-01-12 10:47:02

3------------|--------c------------------------|--------2015-01-12 1:47:02

4------------|--------d------------------------|-------2015-01-10 13:47:02

5------------|--------e------------------------|-------2015-01-10 10:47:02

6------------|--------f------------------------|-------2015-01-10 1:47:02

7------------|--------g------------------------|--------2015-01-9 13:47:02

8------------|--------h------------------------|--------2015-01-9 10:47:02

9------------|--------i------------------------|--------2015-01-9 1:47:02

10------------|--------j-----------------------|--------2015-01-6 13:47:02

11------------|--------k-----------------------|--------2015-01-5 10:47:02

12------------|--------l-----------------------|--------2015-01-2 1:47:02
```

**My output should be:**

```
1------------|--------a------------------------|-------2015-01-12 13:47:02

4------------|--------d------------------------|-------2015-01-10 13:47:02

7------------|--------g------------------------|--------2015-01-9 13:47:02

10------------|--------j-----------------------|--------2015-01-6 13:47:02
```

*But I am getting as all data between the date 2015-01-12 and 2015-01-6.
I want to eliminate the duplicate dates records from output, by only fetching the records of a date which is max out of those duplicate dates(like I eliminated id=2,3 of 2015-01-12 and displaying id 1).*

Comment: what day has your *"2015-01- 13:47:30"* ?

Comment: Check it now @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: I guess your requirement is to retrieve the row with the latest timestamp for each distinct calendar day in your date range.

Comment: Yes, you are right @O.Jones, and another condition I forgot to mention is that, if a keyword is null then select the second latest timestamp. Please see the update in output and input

Answer (score 0):

Use derived table along with sub query

```
select * from mytable where Trackdate IN (
select max(date) from
(
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE TrackDate between DATE_SUB("2015-01-12 13:47:30", INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND "2015-01- 13:47:30"
)tmp
group by date(trackdate)
)
```